# Discrete Math FLT a^p = a mod p, when does it hold true if p is not prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Does 3^39 = 3 mod 39?
I know that 39 is not a prime number thus the FLT theorem a^(p) = a mod p is not necessarily true. But I really want to know how can I find the values that hold true for this statement in {0...38}? I can already see, that 0 and 1 work.

Comment: Values for what? 3^39==27 (mod 39). You can use the Euler-Fermat theorem `a^(phi(n))==1 (mod n)`, where `phi(n)` is Euler's totient function. Anyway, this is a purely mathematical question and is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that to know $x \bmod 39$, you need to know $x \bmod 3$ and $x \bmod 13$: the prime factors of $39$.

We know that $3^k \equiv 3 \pmod 3$ for all values of $k$ (well, all values except $0$). So that's not going to be a constraint.

Fermat's little theorem tells us that $3^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$. Since $3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$, we also have $3^{13} = 3^{12} \cdot 3^1 \equiv 1 \cdot 3 = 3 \pmod{13}$, and more generally that $3^{12k+1} \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$. The powers of $3$ repeat every $12$ steps modulo $13$.

But that's a general fact about powers of anything modulo $13$; powers of $3$ in particular may repeat more often (every $6$ steps, or every $4$ steps, or every $3$ steps, or every $2$). In fact, we have $3^{3} = 27 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, which shows that actually, powers of $3$ repeat every $3$ steps.

In general, we'd want to see when the answers to the two questions (modulo $3$ and modulo $13$) line up, but in this case, it's easy.

We have:

- $3^1 \equiv 3^2 \equiv 3^3 \equiv 3^4 \equiv 3^5 \equiv \dots \equiv 3 \pmod{3}$.
- $3^1 \equiv 3^4 \equiv 3^7 \equiv 3^{10} \equiv 3^{13} \equiv \dots \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$.

So the overlap is just the second list of powers: $1,4,7,10,13,\dots$ are the values of $k$ for which $3^k \equiv 3 \pmod{39}$.